# Basic Mule ESB installation and development

Tags: java, linux, installation, mule, anypoint-studio

I'm new to Mule ESB, so this question, I did some reading about Mule ESB and there is lot of info out there, based on my reading, understand the below as basic setup required for working with Mule ESB, can someone pls confirm ?

1) Linux host with Java 7 (as Java 6 & 8 are not supported)

2) Mule ESB Server installed on Linux Host

3) Mule Anypoint Studio (client - similar to Eclipse for j2ee development)

Basically I want to setup Mule on Linux as run time, so hope the above covers the basic requirements.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1) According to the Release Notes of Mule ESB 3.7.x, Java 8 is supported, (but you can also use Java 7).  However, if you want to install 3.6.x, you can only use Java 7 (again, this is according to the Release Notes).

2) I presume you are referring to the Mule ESB stand-alone runtime which you will install this on your Linux server.

3) Install Anypoint Studio wherever you intend developing your Mule ESB apps (your local desktop or laptop - generally) and 'deploy' them to your server. Note, you will also need to install java to run Anypoint Studio - Java 7 (according to the Release Notes).

Hope that clarifies things...

Comment: Thanks Dylan, this helps, I'm setting up the environment - so this info is handy.